# Read from an NFC Terminal in Android?

Tags: android, nfc

is it possible to read data from an NFC terminal or is the communication unidirectional? I just tried a short implementation and the device does not receive an NFC Intent when tapping it to the terminal.

For example if I use a printer, my Android app could recognize which printer it is etc.

Thank you

Comment: It's possible, but it really depends on the process you used to implement it. Maybe your printer doesn't transmit, it only receives.

Comment: Is that also for example the way that it is done for NFC payment processes? The device of course receives the information about the payment state. So if the device is sending, is the communication technically the same as with an NFC TAG: pIntent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)?

Comment: Tags are readable or writable, but I don't think they can be in both states at once. For the payment example, the register is listening for it to be written to, the phone doesn't read the tag from the terminal, it only discovers the "field" that it is "near" and "communicates"